# Check whether text is highlighted using window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javascript function that needs to check first whether the user has highlighted / selected some text on the page. I read online that this should work:

```
if ( typeof window.getSelection() != "undefined" ) {
    var x = window.getSelection().toString();
}
else {
    //nothing is selected, so use default value
    var x = "default value";
}
```

But that did not work because even when nothing is selected, window.getSelection() returns an object.

```
if ( typeof window.getSelection().toString() !== "" ) {
    var x = window.getSelection().toString();
}
else {
    //nothing is selected, so use default value
    var x = "default value";
}
```

But even though window.getSelection().toString() returns an empty string, it still uses that empty string rather than the default value.

Finally, `if ( window.getSelection() )` did not work either.

How can I know whether something is selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work: http://jsfiddle.net/tknkh9xa/1/

```
(window.getSelection().toString() != "")
```

Your problem was that you were checking the `typeof` on the result of the `toString()`... which would not be an empty string (it would be "string").

Also, since an empty string is a falsy value, you could do just
`if(window.getSelection().toString())`

Comment: if( getSelection()+"" ) is shorter if you're lazy like me.

Comment: I prefer to be more explicit, but that's probably because I usually have several other people who might be looking at or updating the code I write.

Comment: @dandavis What do you mean by "got a kick out"?